# How to fix "No query Unable to fetch row" in qt

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite, qt

I have a simple sqlite3 database containing a couple of names and id's. I want to get the name if the id is given. If i run my program I get the following error:

> ERROR:  "ERROR:  "No query Unable to fetch row"
>   "SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = %1)""

the database name is "dataname" and the table the data is in is "name_table".Below is my code:

```
QSqlDatabase db;
   mInputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
   const QString DRIVER("QSQLITE");
   if(QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable(DRIVER)){

   db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(DRIVER);

}

   db.setHostName("localhost");
   db.setDatabaseName("dataname");

   db.open();

   if(!db.open()){
       qWarning() << "ERROR: " << db.lastError();
   }    
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     mInputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
     QSqlQuery query;
     query.prepare("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = %1");
     query.bindValue("%1", mInputText);

     if(!query.exec())
         qWarning() << "ERROR: " << query.lastError().text();
     qDebug() << query.executedQuery();

     if(query.first())
         ui->mOutputText->setText(query.value(0).toString());
     else
         ui->mOutputText->setText("not found");


}
```

Can someone please help me to find my error.I am new to sql. I think my error might be ".setHostName" or the query bind vallue but i treid everything and i cant get it to work.Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: What does `query.prepare()` call return? It looks like your query has errors. Note the parenthesis at the end!

Comment: I removed the parenthesis and it still doesn't work. The way I understand It is that `query.prepare` and `query.bindValue` is used to set up the query and `query.value(0).toString()` should return a string(whatever the name is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of strugeling I found all of the bugs.

1. `db.setName` needs the file path (and extension) to the database and not just the name of the file:

```
db.setName("C:/User/name/Documents/db.sqlite3");
```

2. I used the placeholders incorrectley ( Thanks @vahancho). It should look like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = ?");
query.bindValue(0, mInputText);`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the placeholders incorrectly. Besides your query string has a syntax error - the closing parenthesis. You might want to try this instead:

```
 [..]
 query.prepare("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = ?");
 query.bindValue(0, mInputText);
 [..]
```

or

```
 [..]
 query.prepare("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = :id");
 query.bindValue(":id", mInputText);
 [..]
```

It also worth to check the what the `QSqlQuery::prepare()` function returns. With it you can catch query errors before you execute them.

Comment: Using these changes the error to "Parameter count mismatch". `QSqlQuery::prepare()` returns `false` (I removed the parenthesis, thanks for pointing it out! but i stil have errors)

Comment: Well, what is the value of `mInputText` variable, when you bind it?

Comment: '1'  (i enter the value into a lineEdit ). It should return the name "Will"

Comment: Is `id` field a text or numeric one? What's its type?

Comment: Numeric(int). I tried changing the string to an integer but it still gives "parameter count mismatch"

Comment: What if you try it without a placeholder and binding. I.e. `query.prepare(QString("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = %1").arg(mInputText));`. What will it return?

Comment: If i say `query.prepare(QString("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = %1").arg(mInputText));` I get a "unable to fetch row error" again

Comment: How your table looks like?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "name_table" (
 "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
 "Name" TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY("id")
);   With 2 names and 2 id's inside(Will,1 and Chris,2)

Answer (score 0):

Replace '=' with 'like'

```
     query.prepare("SELECT name FROM 
     name_table WHERE id like \'%1\' " )
```

Comment: Can you just show the console output of print system.out.print("SELECT name FROM 
     name_table WHERE id like \'%1\' ")

Comment: ERROR:  "No query Unable to fetch row" . When using "like". When using  query.prepare("SELECT name FROM name_table WHERE id = :id") the error is " parameter count mismatch"